# How to remove only the first and last characters from a string in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm trying to take a string that begins and ends with an asterisk and either extract what's between those symbols or Data is in column D.

Here's an example of the data:

[image]

And here's what I've gotten so far:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(D13,"^(.*)\s")`

I would use Substitute, but I can't say with absolute certainty that asterisks won't be used elsewhere in the string. To put it another way, I'm happy to use extract or replace but the only characters I want removed are asterisks and only when they appear at the beginning and/or end of the string but NOT in the middle.

Comment: `"^\*(.*)\*$"` maybe? It would get you `Burgess-Nash Co.` from the above string.

Comment: Just `.(.*).` will even do here. `REGEXEXTRACT` always extracts the first match only.

Comment: Not sure why the `.(.*).` solution is downvoted. I think this perfectly answers this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using MID

```
=MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-2)
```

Using REGEXEXTRACT

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".(.*).")
```

Using REGEXREPLACE

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^.|.$",)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```sql
=REGEXEXTRACT(D13, "^.(.*).$")
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/enuRjO/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
^ asserts position at start of a line
. matches any character, including unicode (except for line terminators)
(.*) - 1st Capturing Group that matches any zero or more characters other than line terminators, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
. matches any character, including unicode (except for line terminators)
$ asserts position at the end of a line
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`MID()`](https://cityInput.value%20=%20%22%22;) function to extract a substring based on position and length.

```
=MID(D13, 2, LEN(D13)-2)
```

This starts from position 2, which skips over the `*` at the beginning, and returns `LEN-2` characters, so it won't include the `*` at the end.

Answer (score -1):

> *"... I'm trying to take a string that begins and ends with an asterisk and either extract what's between those symbols or Data is in column D. ..."*

Additionally, use the *REGEXMATCH* function to assert the starting and ending *asterisk* characters.
And, the *IF* function to distribute the result.

```vb
=IF(REGEXMATCH(D13, "^\*.*\*$"), REGEXEXTRACT(D13, "\*(.+)\*"), D13)
```